# how to install JAWR plugin in maven based grails project

Tags: grails, maven, jawr

I am unable to install JAWR plugin in my maven based grails project, i have tried following commands

```
    mvn grails:install-plugin -DpluginName=Jawr
grails install-plugin Jawr
```

the result of `grails install-plugin Jawr` command is as follows

```
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.EnhancedDefaultDependencyDescriptor.addRuleForModuleId(
) is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleId, java.lang.String) values: [org.slf4j#slf4j-api, compile]
Possible solutions: addRuleForModuleId(org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleId, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:776)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$configureDependencyManager.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.postLoadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:682)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:671)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:653)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:630)
```

the result of mvn `grails:install-plugin -DpluginName=Jawr` command is as follows

```
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.grails.plugins#Jawr;latest.integration: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error resolving plugin [name:Jawr, group:org.grails.plugins, version:latest.integration].
Plugin not found for name [Jawr] and version [not specified]
```

Please help me, if anyone have any idea

thanks in advance

Comment: what is the result of running those commands?

Comment: hi robert, I have edited the question with result of that command please check it and hepl me

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing required entries to the classpath, its not being able to download the jar files...

Check [this link](http://jawr.java.net/docs/jawr_maven_plugin.html), and compare it with your classpath entry.